# Best Alternative to WP List Table

Tags: wp-list-table

According to [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) they are not recommended uss WP List Table. So what is the best alternative to WP List Table?

Answer (score 2):

I've not found any best alternative to this class. The `WP_List_table` is best to use. But the way to use it, is the concern. If you read the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) cafefully you'll see a warning that-

> ***This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers as it is subject to
>   change without warning in any future WordPress release. If you would
>   still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and
>   distribute with your own project, or else use it at your own risk.***

So from here we see the best practice to use the class. ***Copy it, rename it with your prefix and use it in your solution.*** By using this way you'll be safe if the WordPress admin changes anything or make the class deprecated it isn't gonna hurt your code or system or solution.